# How to find the process id of a running java process on mac?

Tags: java, macos, web-applications, jetty, pid

I am trying to find the PID of a java webapp on a Mac.  More specifically, I am trying to find the PID for a jetty webapp running on my Desktop.  I have tried using Activity monitor and searched online all to no avail.

Answer (score 34):

you can use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html), the Java Process Status tool:

```
jps
```

which will show you, for example:

```
13651 RemoteMavenServer
```

on my mac, jps lives in:

```
/usr/bin/jps
```

Comment: Running jps gives me a differnet number all the time; I ran it 3 times and got: 2900, 2901, and 2906.

Comment: Okay, I looked more closely, and it says 384 Jps, 386 Jps, etc.  I guess this is the PID of Jps.  However, I am runnning the webapp at the same time; I can see the proper webpage.  I know the webapp is runnning okay.

Answer (score 10):

Open a terminal and type `jps -v`

Comment: This also gives me differnet numbers everytime.  I got 2924 and 2925

Comment: o.O are you trying to kill it?  it doesn't change unless something is restarting the process or something

Comment: No, but as I said in the ther jps comment, it looks like the PID of Jps is getting returned.  Here is the only line I see: 382 Jps -Dapplication.home=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home -Xms8m

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `ps aux | grep APP_NAME` in Terminal.

Comment: I tried this and like my other commens, the number keeps changing, I got: 2910   0.6  0.0  2435120    476 s001  U+    9:32PM   0:00.01 grep cerebrum and then I got 2923   0.8  0.0  2425704    208 s001  U+    9:36PM   0:00.00 grep cerebrum

Comment: It is the wrong line — you see PID of a `grep`. There is only one line of output in Terminal?

Comment: There is only that line I showed you where the number keeps changing.

Comment: That means, that there is no process named `cerebrum`. Please, try to find target process in full `ps aux` list.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. `jps` gave me no useful information

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

`pgrep -f jetty`

Comment: running "which pgrep" does not return a location on my machine.

Comment: Right. I got it by installing MacPorts